# Laravel composer error -> root composer.json requires adldap2/adldap2-laravel ^6.0

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6

I remove php 8 and I download php 7 after that I try composer update command. But when I run composer update command I have an error.

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- adldap2/adldap2-laravel[v6.0.8, ..., v6.1.5] require adldap2/adldap2 ^10.1 -> satisfiable by adldap2/adldap2[v10.1.0, ..., v10.3.3].
- adldap2/adldap2-laravel[v6.0.0, ..., v6.0.7] require adldap2/adldap2 ^10.0 -> satisfiable by adldap2/adldap2[v10.0.0, ..., v10.3.3].
- adldap2/adldap2[v10.0.0, ..., v10.3.3] require ext-ldap * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's ldap extension.
- Root composer.json requires adldap2/adldap2-laravel ^6.0 -> satisfiable by adldap2/adldap2-laravel[v6.0.0, ..., v6.1.5].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- C:\xampp\php\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Comment: The error is pretty clear *ext-ldap -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's ldap extension*. You must have had this extension enabled with php8 but did not enable it with php 7

Comment: enable  ext-ldap  on php 7.4 in xampp